# How can I correlate groups of variables?

Tags: correlation, spss

I have conducted a survey to find out the correlation between organizational justice and turnover intention within an organization. So, in the survey, I have asked some Likert-scale questions around organizational justice and some around turnover intention. When I enter the data into SPSS, I have to enter each question as one variable. It means that there will be some variables about organizational justice and some variables about turnover intention.

My problem is that I don't know how to group these variables into two main variables -"organizational justice" and "turnover intention" in SPSS. Does anyone have any idea about what I can do?

Comment: There might be a stats questions here but it's hard to tell. The way you've asked it, it sounds like it's about coding in SPSS. If it really is just coding then it's inappropriate for CrossValidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple potentially correlated variables for both 'Organizational justice' and 'turnover intention' you might want to use Principle Component Analysis or a factor analysis-based method to reduce the dimensionality of your data.

By using PCA, you'll be able to summarise many correlated variables into one variable that explains the largest proportion of the variance for your data (PC1).

Therefore, if a large proportion of the variance is accounted for (>80%) in PC1 for organizational justice, and the same when you perform PCA for 'turnover intention' you'll have two principle component variables that represent both.

You could then correlate those two separate PCs to see how organisational justice and turnover relate to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. As I understand, PCA will help me to find out the most relevant factor as a representatives of " org justice" and " turnover intention". However, I am thinking that there are many facets of an issue and it's equally meaningful to be analyzed. So, if we choose "the principle component", then there will be many facets missing and will the result be still reliable?

Comment: You would have to see. If you calculate PC1 and it explains a very large proportion of the variance (I would say >80%) I would say you wouldn't be missing much. The other 20% could be meaningful but it could also be noise (people not answering properly).

You could also look at the loadings of the PC and see what's contributing the most to explain the variation observed.

Comment: If, after that, you still would like to analyse everything, potentially just make a correlation matrix of all the variables representing 'org justice' and all the variables representing 'turnover intention' - potentially correcting for multiple testing.

Comment: Thank you. It does make sense to me. I may study more about PCA and come up with a decision. Your comment is really helpful. Thank you.